# Pandas Grouping Select entire Column

Tags: pandas

I used the pandas groupby method to get the following dataframe.  How do I select an entire column from this dataframe, say the column named EventID or Value.

df['Value'] gives the entire dataFrame back, not just the Value column.

```
                                     Value
Realization   Occurrence   EventID              
1             207          2023378    20
              213          2012388    25
              291          2012612    28
              324          2036783    12
              357          2255910    45
              399          2166643    64
              420          2022922    19
2             207          2010673    56
              249          2018319    77
              282          2166809    43
```

Answer (score 2):

`df['Value']` *is* just the Value column. The reason why there is so much other data attached is because `df['Value']` has a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) with three levels.

To drop the MultiIndex, you could use

```
df['Value'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or, you could get a NumPy array of the underlying data using

```
df['Value'].values
```